# Strange DateTime format

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, unix-timestamp, epoch

Please help me to figure out how to parse this strange date-time string with ruby:

`"TimeStampUtc": "\/Date(1328696521000+0000)\/`

`"Date"=>"/Date(1365703200000+0100)/`

Comment: try: `Date.at(1365703200000+0100)`

Answer (score 1):

with the trailing 0's, it's probably a javascript-style timestamp: milliseconds since jan 1/1970:

```
1365703200000/1000 = 136570320 -> Apr 11/2013
```